# java regexp parse partial title tag

Tags: java, regex

Ok, quick question. I'm a bit of a newbie at Java, and I have an assignment in which I have to get the name of a person from the title tag of a page. I know my regex, but I can't (or don't know how) to escape some characters.

Example

```
<title>Mr. Somebody | Department in which he's in</title>
```

So, basically I need a regexp that would get me the "Mr. Somebody". I've tried :

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("<title>(.+?)|");                               
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(data);
boolean found = false;
while (!found && mat.find()) {
      name = mat.group(0);
      found = true;
}
System.out.println("Found a name : " + name);
```

My problem is, that no matter what I've tried, the most I could get was the first character. Do you think that a more simpler approach with indexOf and substrings would be better, or is a regexp still viable?

I know that usually regexps are not suitable for parsing html tags, but I'm considering this search more of a string search, because I'm not interested in the whole tag (or other tags that might be contained within).

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the pipe because it's a character with a special meaning in regex. Try:

```
<title>(.+?)\\|
```

`|` means "or" which means that the regex will try to match with either `<title>(.+?)` or nothing (there's nothing after the `|`.

When it tries to match with `<title>(.+?)`, it will get only the first character because `.+?` is lazy (it matches as little as possible).

Alternatively, you can use a negated class:

```
<title>([^\\|]+)
```

`[^\\|]+` will match any character except a pipe.

Comment: Just to make a little bit clear, you have to use double backslash (as @Jerry did) because you need the bar to be compiled in order to escape the character, but a single backslash wouldn't suffice because you are in a string, then you need to escape the string backslash in order to get the regex escaped. There is some really good and in-depth info about regex here http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html

Comment: @CaioToOn Right on. Thanks for elaborating!

Comment: Thanks guys, I did want to escape initially, (`\|`), but apparently it you have to escape the escape in Java. 

Thanks, you've been really helpful! :D

Answer (score 0):

It should work

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("<title>(.*?)\\|");
```

and use

```
mat.group(1) instead of mat.group(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it that will avoid using Pattern and Matcher, if you want:

```
String name = "<title>Mr. Somebody | Department in which he's in</title>";
name = name.substring(7).replaceAll("\\|.*", "");
```

The substring(7) will remove the first  tag, then replaceAll will remove everything from the pipe character onwards (replace with empty string).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this it what you want:

```
(?<=<title>)(.+?(?=[|].+?))(?=.+?</title>)
```

It returns Mr. Somebody. You can test it [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/) for example.

Comment: Thanks for this, more elaborate example :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way :

```
<\s*title[^>]*>\s*([^\|]+)
```

- Takes away leading white space.
- Handles any possible weird attributes that someone may add to a title tag, i.e. `<title data-cookies="I hide cookies here :P">I like titles</title>`
- Handles any whitespace added before title, i.e. `<            title    >` is still valid.